# Displaying a list of user controls in flow document

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I need to create a printable representation of my data and since I have created some control to edit the data entities I thought I could drop that into a flow document one after the other using a listbox or something similar and a get a first printable version. I made some proof-of-concept via:

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
  <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDoc" PageWidth="793" PageHeight="1122" Background="AntiqueWhite" PagePadding="48" ColumnWidth="793">
    <Paragraph>
      <v:DisplayEntityV DataContext="{Binding MySample, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource AppDataContext}}" />
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocument>
```

If I change the paragraph like this

```
<Paragraph>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfSamples, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource AppDataContext}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <v:DisplayEntityV DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Paragraph>
```

I get only one paragraph and there is no page break between the `DisplayEntityV` where appropriate. I got to the conclusion that for my case it must be the other way round: the inner structure should be the paragraph and the outer structure should be a list, but I can use only `List` within `FlowDocument` which creates a bulleted list and has no data binding capabilities.

I really would prefer to have something like a listbox to which I can bind my items I want to display (because that gives me the advantage to see at design time how it will look like at least with sample data) rather than adding the items in code behind at run time. Any suggestions are highly welcome.